# Creating logic to select string variable based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm attempting to extend the functionality of a weather script I'm writing.  Currently it is designed to display the current weather in JSON output based on the input of the user.

```
response = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather')
```

`weather` is the correct URL to generate current weather data, but I also want to generate a 3 or 5 days weather forecast, but based on the user input.

I have been using `argparse` a bit for user data, but I'm thinking of something like this to decide if `weather` should be used at the end of the string or `forecast`.

```
parser.add_argument("-data", help="current weather or 5 day")
```

But what I'm having trouble with is the logic to decide based on the input, whether a person decides current weather or a 5 day forecast, how I would be able to do that.

Should I use some sort of try statement in my function to determine which string to add, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at http://openweathermap.org/api and after seeing the URLs it is unclear to me what is the question. Current weather's URL ends with `weather?q={parameters}` and forcast's URL ends with `forcast?q={parameters}`.

It seems to me that what you are looking for is an option that will tell you which URL to query.

Why not setting an option in the `argparse` like `--forcast`, If the option is set by the user then query the `forcast` URL. Assuming you query the `weather` URL by default.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to find a way to determine which URL to query.  That gives me more to think about.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the docs for `openweathermap.org` to find out how you specify this option in the URL. From there you have to decide how your own users will specify the option and write code that translates the input for your program to the correct URL. If you are using command-line arguments, then you just have to parse the arguments and use an `if` statement to create the URL.